# Figuring out physical address by hand (The IDTR register)

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers, memory-segmentation

I've been trying to figure this one for a long time now and I'm not getting anywhere.

Here is what I'm trying to do:
At what physical address in protected mode is the interrupt vector number 3 located if the value contained in IDTR is 0x3A000?

I want to find a formula which will help me calculate the physical address of every single byte of the interrupt vector #3's offset and also the physical address of every single byte of the interrupt vector #3's segment.

I've been looking around the internet and there is no solid explanation of how the IDTR to calculate this and I'm really curious.

I'm also curious about how this same physical address is found for the real mode...

If someone can help me find a general formula for solving this kind of a question it would be a blast!

Comment: I  real mode it's easy, because the address is the address. :-) In protected mode it really shouldn't matter, because the processor translates the virtual address on each access.

Answer (score 4):

I've found the answer. Tnx to Jester & the links. :D

Here's an image that shows the relationship of the IDTR (Interrupt Descriptor Table Register) and IDT (Interrupt Descriptor Table). (Reference: Intel's manual):

[image]

Here's also a pricture that shows how the entries in the IDT look like (Reference: Intel's manual):

[image]

The base address(the address where the IDT starts) of the IDT (Interrupt Description Table) is given by the bits 16 to 47, 16 and 47 inclusive. To get the address of the vector #3 the size of the first 2 entries has to be added to the base address. To find the addresses where the bits for the offset and for the segment selector reside one needs to find the address of the vector and then add bytes according to the second picture, so to say one moves inside an entry of the IDT.

"The base addresses of the IDT should be aligned on an 8-byte boundary to maximize performance of cache line 
fills. The limit value is expressed in bytes and is added to the base address to get the address of the last valid byte. 
A limit value of 0 results in exactly 1 valid byte. Because IDT entries are always eight bytes long, the limit should 
always be one less than an integral multiple of eight (that is, 8N – 1).
The IDT may reside anywhere in the linear address space.As shown in Figure 6-1, the processor locates the IDT 
using the IDTR register. This register holds both a 32-bit base address and 16-bit limit for the IDT." - (Reference: Intel's manual)

So one should align the table as it is said in the manual for better performance.
For educational purposes I'll explain how to find the physical addresses of the offset bytes and the segment bytes when the IDTR contains 3A000h.

Procedure:

First I'll write 3A000h in binary format so it is easier to understand the number using the picture.

So 3A000h becomes: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0011 1010 0000 0000 0000
Note: It is a 48 digit number because the IDTR is 48 bits long.

The base address is the number that starts at bit 16 and ends at bit 47. So:

[image]

The base address = 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0011
and that's 3h.

So the first entry is at physical address 3.

To get the third entry one adds the size of the 2 entries before it so the address of the third entry is:

3+2*8=19=13h

The 2 entries are multiplied by 8 because one entry is 8 bytes long.

Now to get the physical address of the offset bytes, we just need to look at the figure 6.2 and see that entries look like this:

[image]

So reading from the picture

The physical addresses of the segment selector are:

19+2  and  19+2+1

or

13h+2h and 13h+2h+1h

The physical addresses of the offset bytes are (assuming it's an interrupt or a trap gate):
19, 19+1, 19+6, 19+7

or

13h, 13h+1, 13h+6h, 13h+7h

---

**The General Procedure For Solving This Kind Of Problem:**

BaseAddress=IDTR/(2^16) -> Integer division

Limit=IDTR%(2^16)

VectorPhysicalAddress=BaseAddress+(VectorNumber-1)*8

Physical addresses of the segments selector bytes are: VectorPhysicalAddress+2 and VectorPhysicalAddress+3

Physical addresses of the offset bytes are: VectorPhysicalAddress, VectorPhyscialAddress+1, VectorPhysicalAddress+6, VectorPhysicalAddress+7

Answer (score 0):

I am kind of puzzled why you didn't read the intel manuals instead of "looking around the internet". Granted, said [manuals are available on the internet](http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/) too.

If you care to read *section 6.10 INTERRUPT DESCRIPTOR TABLE (IDT)* in the *Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual Volume 3A: System Programming Guide, Part 1* you will see that the IDTR contains a linear base address (bits 16-47) and a limit (bits 0-15). Also note the manual says *the limit should always be one less than an integral multiple of eight*, as such, your example of `0x3a000` is not valid (`3` isn't a particularly sensible base address either). To get physical address, you have to go through the normal paging mechanism, if enabled. The handler for each interrupt is defined by a 8 byte descriptor in the table. For more details see the manual.

In real mode, interrupt vectors are 4 byte far pointers starting at physical address 0.